# Find the minimum of an expression with multiple constraints

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I need help to find a value for "**d**" which the expr has the minimum value at that "**d**" value. Constraints are added to the code

```
ClearAll[c, x1, y1, x2, y2, d, expr]
c = 5;
expr = -x1*y1*c + x2*y2*c + d*x1*x2;
FindMinimum[{expr,
  x2*y2 + 2*c*y2 - d*x1*x2 < 0 &&
  -x1*y1 + 2*c*y1 - d*x1*x2 < 0 && 
  x1 + x2 == 1 &&
  y1 + y2 == 1 && 
  x1 > 0 && 
  x2 > 0 && 
  y1 >= 0 &&
  y2 >= 0}, {d}]
```

The code above doesn't give me any values for "**d**" and I don't get any errors. I don't know what the problem is with this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To minimize symbolically,[Minimize](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Minimize.html)
works here.

```
ClearAll[c, x1, y1, x2, y2, d, expr]
c = 5;
expr = -x1*y1*c + x2*y2*c + d*x1*x2;
Minimize[{expr, 
  x2*y2 + 2*c*y2 - d*x1*x2 < 0 && -x1*y1 + 2*c*y1 - d*x1*x2 < 0 && 
   x1 + x2 == 1 && y1 + y2 == 1 && x1 > 0 && x2 > 0 && y1 >= 0 && 
   y2 >= 0}, {d}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This indicates that `d` is `Indeterminate`

Comment: Hi @Xminer thanks for your help. The code you provided works. 
-@BobHanlon you are right "d" is Inderterminate and I need to give initial values for x1, x2, y1 and, y2.

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

c = 5;
```

Eliminate unnecessary variables `{x2, y2}`

```
expr = -x1*y1*c + x2*y2*c + d*x1*x2 /. {x2 -> 1 - x1, y2 -> 1 - y1} // 
  Simplify

(* 5 + (-5 + d) x1 - d x1^2 - 5 y1 *)

var = Variables[Level[expr, {-1}]];

cons = x2*y2 + 2*c*y2 - d*x1*x2 < 0 && -x1*y1 + 2*c*y1 - d*x1*x2 < 0 && 
     1 > x1 > 0 && 1 >= y1 >= 0 /. {x2 -> 1 - x1, y2 -> 1 - y1} // Simplify;

min = FindMinimum[Evaluate[List @@ (expr && cons)], var, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 15]

(* {2.10526275527238, {d -> 1.46032188433906*10^7, x1 -> 0.999999675630191, 
  y1 -> 0.526316126809388}} *)

expr /. min[[2]]

(* 2.1052628 *)
```

Comment: Hi @Bob Hanlon, I ran your code and I get different value for "d"
following is the results that I get:
{2.10535857973380, {d -> 269407.8237226680, x1 -> 0.999982417241665, 
  y1 -> 0.5263157407680821}}

Comment: I copied, pasted, and executed the code above and got the results as shown above. I am using version 12.0 on macOS 10.15.2

Comment: still I get the same results, {2.10535857973380, {d -> 269407.8237226680, x1 -> 0.999982417241665, 
  y1 -> 0.5263157407680821}}. I am using version 8 of Mathematica

Comment: Version 8 is pretty old. Perhaps you are using a 32-bit version rather than 64-bit. The minimum appears to occur as `d` grows unbounded so any small deviation in `{x1, y1}` would cause large changes in `d`.

Answer (score 1):

With variable substitution `d -> 1/dd` (together with the variable elimination by @Bob Hanlon) you can easily get an analytical solution (for values at the boundary).

```
c = 5;

expr = -x1*y1*c + x2*y2*c + d*x1*x2 /. {x2 -> 1 - x1, y2 -> 1 - y1} //
Simplify

cons = x2*y2 + 2*c*y2 - d*x1*x2 < 0 && -x1*y1 + 2*c*y1 - d*x1*x2 < 0 &&
 1 > x1 > 0 && 1 >= y1 >= 0 /. {x2 -> 1 - x1, y2 -> 1 - y1} // 
Simplify

mi = Minimize[{expr, cons} /. d -> 1/dd, {dd, x1, y1}, Reals]

(*   Minimize::wksol: Warning: There is no minimum in the region in which the objective function is defined and the constraints are satisfied; returning a result on the boundary. >>   *)

(*   {40/19, {dd -> 0, x1 -> 1, y1 -> 10/19}}   *)
```

Comment: Hi @Akku14  the code works. Thank you. 
Is there a way to have contour plot to show the minimum values of d for different values of x1 and y1 on two axises?

Comment: The minimal allowed d for certain x1,y1 according to cons?  `mind = Minimize[{d, cons}, {d}, Reals]` Absolute allowed min of d  `mindabs = Minimize[{d, cons}, {d, x1, y1}, Reals] // N` .  `gr = Graphics3D[{PointSize[Large], Red, 
    Point[{x1, y1, d} /. mindabs[[2]]]}];`  `pl = Plot3D[mind[[1]], {x1, 0, 1}, {y1, 0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 100
  ];`  `cp = ContourPlot[mind[[1]], {x1, 0, 1}, {y1, 0, 1}, 
  Contours -> {21, 40, 60, 80, 100}, ContourShading -> None, 
  MaxRecursion -> 3, 
  Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Red, Point[{x1, y1} /. mindabs[[2]]]}]`  `Show[pl, gr]` .

Comment: Get the minimum of expr for all possible d  `mimi = Minimize[{expr, cons}, {d}, Reals]`  `Plot3D[mimi[[1]], {x1, 0, 1}, {y1, 0, 1}]`  and the known overall minimum  `Minimize[mimi[[1, 1, 1]], {x1, y1}, Reals]`